# Jquery + Flowplayer: Video playback problems on IE after get a new page with ajax

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, flowplayer

Here is an example of a problem.
http://www.playpersdesign.com/design/test_vdo.html

Try to play the video sequence. Then press the load. Then press play again. You will find the subproblems in IE.

Thanks for helping.